# Bruteforce https post using single tcp connection

Tags: tls, http, brute-force

So I've tried bruteforcing my server using thc-hydra's https-post-form, but it floods the server very quickly and the requests start timing out.

However, If I go through the browser where the HTTP header Connection: Keep Alive is used and accepted by the server, I can make a lot of requests in rapid succession without flooding the server.

Is there a tool like hydra that can be used to send many https post requests using a single tcp connection?

Comment: Bash script which executes a cURL command to login.

Comment: Try intruder tab in burp

Comment: @VipulNair From what I've read, the Burp intruder makes a new connection for each request, I might be misinformed though.